# Best Practice to Float a View over Another View?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, popup

I have a 320x460 view with a number of buttons, depending on the button pressed, a 280x280 view pops up over the 320x460 view (similar to the behavior of the UIAlertView) using code like this:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 280)];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[overlayView autorelease];
[overlayView addSubview:label]; // label declared elsewhere
[overlayView addSubview:backgroundImage]; // backgroundImage declared elsewhere
    //... Add a bunch of other controls

    [label release];
    [backgroundImage release];
    //... Release a bunch of other controls

[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Everything works fine displaying the overlayView and all its controls.

The question I have is, how do I get rid of the overlayView once it's displayed? I want to make it not only not visible but to remove it completely, since the user will be popping up the overlayView repeatedly during use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need access to overlayView to remove it, I'd suggest adding this to the create side:

```
overlayView.tag = 5; // Or some other non-zero number
```

Then later you can use it like this:

```
-(void)removeOverlayView
{
     UIView *overlayView = [self.view viewWithTag:5];
     [overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}
```